# What filesystem to use for USB hard drive to be shared with Samba - Ubuntu Server 20.04.1

Tags: server, hard-drive, filesystem, samba

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 installed on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+

I want to plug in a USB hard drive and have the files stored there shared to MacOS, Windows 10, and various Linux machines.

Does the filesystem matter? Which one would be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba can share from any file system your system can use.  I use the ext file systems native to Linux.  Others may prefer the z or the btrfs file systems which offer some added features.  It's really up to you.  Samba just piggy-backs off of your system and doesn't share the underlying file system directly.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your answer!